# BackboneJS - Why double-click to fire event?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, magnific-popup

I have a Backbone App, using HandlebarsJS for my HTML templates. Now I have a button to trigger a login popup box. My issue is, that I have to double-click the button/link until the popup opens. Why is that?? I'm using the `Magnific Popup`-plugin. Maybe it has to do with that?

My HTML looks like this:

```
<li>
   <a href="#" class="login">
      <span>Login</span>
   </a> 
</li>
```

And in my Backbone View I have:

```
events: {
    'click .login': 'login',
},

login: function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('.login').magnificPopup({
            items: {
                src: '#loginbox',
                disableOn: 700,
                type: 'inline',
                mainClass: 'mfp-fade',
                removalDelay: 160,
                preloader: false,
                fixedContentPos: false
            },
            closeBtnInside: false
        });
 }
```

The loginbox itself, is in the same HTMl file where the login link is.

Can anyone help me out? thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I solved by myself:

```
$('.login').magnificPopup({
        items: {
            src: '#loginbox',
            disableOn: 700,
            type: 'inline',
            mainClass: 'mfp-fade',
            removalDelay: 160,
            preloader: false,
            fixedContentPos: false
        },
        closeBtnInside: false
    }).magnificPopup('open');
```

After adding `.magnificPopup('open');` it works!!!

Answer (score 1):

Change `e.stopPropagation();` to `e.preventDefault()`. What's happening, is that the first time you click, the URL is changing to "/#", then you click it again, and because it's already on the "/#" URL, is actions the rest of your code. `e.preventDefault()` will stop the browser following the # link.